# Centos 6 - Can't get out of safe mode

Tags: centos, mysql, centos-6

So I was going into safe mode from following a tut to fix the error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

And I had issued the following command:

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=mysql-init.txt &
```

Now I can't get out of safe mode, even rebooting my VPS wont fix it.

Trying to start mysqld I get this:

```
Another MySQL daemon already running with the same unix socket.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html) is a program that manage the launch of [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html) and waits for a return value to determine id mysqld had terminate gracefully (via a normal shutdown) or not. In some instances, mysqld_safe will attempt to restart mysqld if it crashes.

You should kill the mysqld_safe process in memory.

Then, run

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown
```

Last resort, kill mysqld.

Comment: I also found a solution. Was told to just move the sock file in the mysql folder else where.